# Calling a function that is inside a class from other class

Tags: php, class

Lets suppose I have a PHP file `file1.php`. Something like this:

```
<?php
class sqlClass {
public function one { //do something }
?>
```

Then in other PHP file `file2.php`, I have this:

```
<?php 
class encryption_class {
public function two { //do something }
}
```

How can I call the function `two` which is inside the class `encryption_class` inside the `file2.php` from the function `one` on the `file1.php` class `sqlClass`?

Comment: You would have to instantiate the `encryption_class` within the `sqlClass`. Or create a static method or use a singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First include `file2` in `file1`

```
include_once "file2.php";
```

Then create object and call.

```
$a = new encryption_class ();
$a->two();
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<?php

require_once "file2.php"; 

class sqlClass {
    public function one {
        //do something

        $encript = new encryption_class();
        $encript->two(); 

    }
}
```